# Google Calendar Feed that displays Time, Date and Event in "normal" format in browser

Tags: php, date, time, google-calendar-api, feed

When the code below is run in a browser it displays the date and evet like this:

> 2013-10-30T05:30:00.000-07:00 - 2013-10-30T06:30:00.000-07:00 Envent 2
>
> 2013-10-29T23:00:00.000-07:00 - 2013-10-30T00:00:00.000-07:00 Event 1

I'd like to be able to separate Date, Time and Event into their own editable ID's but am not sure how to target the parameter for each.

For instance, it would look more like this:

> Event 2 - October 30th 2013, 5:30PM to 6:30PM
>
> Event 1 - October 29th 2013, 11:00PM to 12:00AM

The Code:

```
$email = "yourEmail";
//your calendar has to be made public under calendar settings
$url = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/".$email."/public/full";
$xml = file_get_contents($url);

$feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$ns=$feed->getNameSpaces(true);

foreach ($feed->entry as $entry) {
    $when=$entry->children($ns["gd"]);
    $when_atr=$when->when[0]->attributes();
    $start=$when_atr['startTime'];
    $end=$when_atr['endTime'];
    $title=$entry->title;

    echo "<p>".$title." ".$start." - ".$end."</p>";
}
```

I found this [article](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) which was helpful, however, I can't figure out how to make it relative to Google Calendar.

Comment: Looks like you have three separate variables containing the three pieces of information you want already – so if you want to output them in a different HTML structure, modify the part where that’s done. And if you want to format the dates differently, parse them into a unix timestamp first (f.e. using strtotime or a DateTime object), and output them in the desired format afterwards.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for the input. I came across the timestamp methods, but I went another route which seems to work for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **[Date and Time extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)**.

Example:

```
$start = new DateTime($when_atr['startTime']);
```

[Demo for the same dates](https://eval.in/58776).

Comment: thanks for the input. You answer ended up helping me out a lot. Take a look at my answer above and tell me what you think. It seems to display the date in time in a fashion I was after. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @WoolfFaulkner: np. But since all you did is copy my advice to your code, there is no need you to answer this question. Best regards

Comment: I appreciate the help. I'm somewhat new to using stack and PHP, and I find it helpful when other users post solutions. Thus I'm posting this one. Also, I'd like to point although you method was helpful is wasn't the immediate solution, there was still more to be done to address what I initially asked. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research and help from the those in this thread I was able to get this answered!

The PHP

```
<?php 
$email = "your public calendar address email";
$url = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/".$email."/public/full";
$xml = file_get_contents($url);

$feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$ns=$feed->getNameSpaces(true);

foreach ($feed->entry as $entry) {
    $when=$entry->children($ns["gd"]);
    $when_atr=$when->when[0]->attributes();

    $title=$entry->title;
    echo "<div class='eventTitle'>".$title . "</div>";

    $start = new DateTime($when_atr['startTime']);
    echo "<div class='eventTime'>".$start->format('D F jS, g:ia') . " to ";    

    $end = new DateTime($when_atr['endTime']);
    echo $end->format('g:ia')."</div>" . '<br />' ;    



}

 ?>
```

The CSS

```
<style>

 .eventTime {
    color:#0CF;
 }

 .eventTitle {
    color:#0FC; 
 }

 </style>
```

The following resources were helpful:

[Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), [Date and Time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php), and the [Example](https://eval.in/58776) @Glavić posted.